# ASP.NET Core WCF proxy bypass list

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy, asp.net-core-mvc

I am currently working on a new web project at work using ASP.NET Core 1.0 and MVC 6. For this project I have added a SOAP web service via Add Service Reference so that it is now a WCF.

The company site is built in web forms and the SOAP web service is used via adding a Web Reference. The issue with the web service is by passing the company proxy. The company site uses WebProxy to accomplish this. However in the new ASP.NET Core project, WebProxy is not included. Now I know I can implement it myself using IWebProxy (which I've actually done) but I don't know how to go about attaching it to the WCF. I have tried adding a BasicHttpBinding in code but there's no proxy extension.

I have also tried adding my implementation of IWebProxy into Startup via a middleware extension to no avail.

Does anyone know how I can go about adding a proxy bypass list to the WCF? I have been at this for a few days and I'm not able to find anything that is helpful.